# Sitecore Package installation not working

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I am trying to install Sitecore PowerShell Extensions-3.0 Package for Sitecore 8
in my sitecore 8 instance (Windows 8.1 machine).

I used Sitecore's Development Tools -> Installation Wizard & Package Manager and choosing the above mentioned package. It shows Install a Package sitecore dialog with Installing gif and stays there for over an hour and nothing happens. No error nothing it just spins.

First I tried other Packages and it was the same, even with lower versions of Powershell Packages and it still doesn't install.

Can someone shed some lights on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

When installing Sitecore packages entries are written to the Sitecore Log. In Sitecore 8 the Logs are stored in MongoDB, so if you don't have Mongo running installing packages appears to hang.

Although disabling Mongo Analytics allowed you to install the package it is not a suitable method moving forward. Instead you should install [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads?_ga=1.4803958.416317107.1436517068) and then get the Sitecore DBs running by executing a .bat file.

To do that open Notepad paste the text as it below, modifying the path to the MongoDB.exe and folder containing the Sitecore Mongo databases if required, then Save As SitecoreDbs.bat

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin\mongod.exe" -dbpath "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Sitecore8\Databases"
```

Essentially the path to your MongoDB executable location and the Path to your Site's databases.

Answer (score 0):

By disabling Mongo Analytic did the trick.